# What is the best way to write and append a large file in java

Tags: java, web-services, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I have a java program that sends a series of GET requests to a webservice and stores the response body as a text file.

I have implemented the following example code (filtered much of the code to highlight the concerned) which appends the text file and writes as a new line at the EOF. The code, however, works perfectly but the performances suffers as the size of the file grows bigger.

The total size of data is almost 4 GB and appends about 500 KB to 1 MB of data on avg.

```
do
{
    //send the GET request & fetch data as string
    String resultData = HTTP.GET <uri>;

    // buffered writer to create a file 
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));

    //write or append the file
    writer.write(resultData + "\n");
}
while(resultData.exists());
```

These files are created on daily basis and moved to hdfs for hadoop consumption and as a real-time archive. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you re-opening the writer for each individual request? Just open it once, before the do-while loop. Don't forget to close it after the do-while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You are opening a new `writer` every time, without closing the previous `writer` object.

2) Don't open the file for each write operation, instead open it before the loop, and close it after the loop.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));
do{
          String resultData = HTTP.GET <uri>;
          writer.write(resultData + "\n");
}while(resultData.exists());
writer.close();
```

3) Default buffered size of `BufferedWriter` is 8192 characters, Since you have 4 GB of data, I would increase the buffer size, to improve the performance but at the same time make sure your JVM has enough memory to hold the data.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, true), 8192 * 4);
do{
          String resultData = HTTP.GET <uri>;
          writer.write(resultData + "\n");
}while(resultData.exists());
writer.close();
```

4) Since you are making a GET web service call, the performance depends on the `response` time of `webservice` also.

Comment: I want to open a file every time for safety (in case power is gone), so what is the solution for this case? Does `FileWriter` read all the file just to add a new content at the end?

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer [Java difference between FileWriter and BufferedWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350248/java-difference-between-filewriter-and-bufferedwriter) what you are doing right now is inefficient.

The code you provided is incomplete. Brackets are missing, no `close` statement for the writer. But if I understand correctly for every `resultData` you open a new buffered writer and call write **once** . This means that you should use the `FileWriter` directly, since the way you are doing it, the buffer is just an overhead.

If what you want it to get data in a loop and write them in a single file, then you should do something like this

```
try( BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("PATH_HERE", true)) ) {
    String resultData = "";

    do {
        //send the GET request & fetch data as string
        resultData = HTTP.GET <uri>;

        //write or append the file
        writer.write(resultData + "\n");

    } while(resultData != null && !resultData.isEmpty());

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above uses [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), which will handle closing the writer after exiting the `try` block. This is available in java 7.