# Difference between the two types for writing into file

Tags: java, nio

I am going through Java's NIO class from Java 8.

```
Path dataPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("SomeFile");

Files.write(dataPath,"\n Hello".getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

and

```
Path dataPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("SomeFile");
BufferedWriter locFile = Files.newBufferedWriter(dataPath);

locFile.write("\n Hello");
```

Is it just that we are writing in terms of Bytes with Files.write() and Using a BufferedWriter for directly writing the text ?

Comment: For one thing, you're using different options. For another you're using a `BufferedWriter`. I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I'm just trying to find the difference between two implementations. Both of them are used to write into a File. So which is more preferred in different situations ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350364/1553851

Comment: just these two? there are more :-) you can start here: http://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file