# Multithreaded Geometry loading with GeoTools

Tags: java, multithreading, shapefile, geotools, jts

Hey StackOverflow community,
I am currently trying to write a little tool, that reads a shapefiles geometries (Multipolygons / Polygons) and writes the WKT-representations of those into a text file.
To do so, I am using GeoTools and I managed to get it running fine, due to the fact that I am converting files with about 5000000 Polygons / Multipolygons, it takes pretty long to finish.

So my question is:

Is it possible to fasten up the file loading/writing?
As I am using a SimpleFeatureIterator I did not find out how to implement multithreading.

Is there a way to do so?
Or does anyone know, how to get the shapefiles geometries without using an iterator?

**This is my code:**

This method is just stating the File Chooser and starting the thread for each selected file.

```
protected static void printGeometriesToFile() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "shape-files", "shp");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose the file to be converted.");
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    File[] files = null;

    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultiThreadWriter writer = new MultiThreadWriter(files[i]);
        writer.start();
    }
}
```

The class for multithreading:

```
class MultiThreadWriter extends Thread {
    private File threadFile;

    MultiThreadWriter(File file) {
        threadFile = file;
        System.out.println("Starting Thread for " + file.getName());
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            File outputFolder = new File(threadFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);
            System.out.println("Now writing data to file: " + outputFolder.getName());

            FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(threadFile);
            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

            SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();
            SimpleFeatureIterator featureIterator = featureCollection.features();

            int pos = 0;

            while (featureIterator.hasNext()) {
                fos.write((geometryToByteArray((Polygonal) featureIterator.next().getAttribute("the_geom"))));

                pos++;
                System.out.println("The file " + threadFile.getName() + "'s current positon is: " + pos);
            }

            fos.close();

            System.out.println("Finished writing.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a helper function that converts the Multipolygons to polygons and returns its WKT-representation with a "|" as a seperator.

```
private byte[] geometryToByteArray(Polygonal polygonal) {

    List<Polygon> polygonList;

    String polygonString = "";

    if (polygonal instanceof MultiPolygon) {
        polygonList = GeometrieUtils.convertMultiPolygonToPolygonList((MultiPolygon) polygonal);
     //The method above just converts a MultiPolygon into a list of Polygons
    } else {
        polygonList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        polygonList.add((Polygon) polygonal);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < polygonList.size(); i++) {
        polygonString = polygonString + polygonList.get(i).toString() + "|";
    }

    return polygonString.getBytes();
}
```

}

I know my code is not pretty or good. I have just started learning Java and hope it will become better soon.

sincerely

ihavenoclue :)

Comment: The real question is why do you want a text file of 5000000 wkt polygons? Using a database would probably be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need create a new thread for every file, because creating new thread is an expensive operation. Instead, you can let `MultiThreadWriter`  implements `Runnable` and use `ThreadPoolExecuter` manage all threads.

   MultiThreadWriter

   ```
   public class MultiThreadWriter implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           //
       }
   }
   ```

   Create thread pool matches your runtime processors.

   ```
   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

   for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       MultiThreadWriter writer = new MultiThreadWriter(files[i]);
       service.submit(writer);
   }
   ```
2. You can use `BufferedWriter` instead `OutputStream`, it is [more
   efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350248/java-difference-between-filewriter-and-bufferedwriter) when you repeatly write small pieces.

   ```
   File outputFolder = new File(threadFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFolder);
   BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fos);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefere to read files content as a list of objects, then split the list onto sublists, then create a thread to each list, example :

```
int nbrThreads = 10;

ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nbrThreads);

int count = myObjectsList != null ? myObjectsList.size() / nbrThreads : 0;

List<List<MyObject>> resultlists = choppeList(myObjectsList, count > 0 ? count : 1);

try
{
    for (List<MyObject> list : resultlists)
    {
        // TODO : create your thread and passe the list of objects   
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTESS); // chose time of termination
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LOG.error("Problem launching threads", e);
}
```

The choppeList method can be like that :

```
public <T> List<List<T>> choppeList(final List<T> list, final int L)
{
    final List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L)
    {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L))));
    }
    return parts;
}
```